# Invoke all EJB in clustered environment

Tags: tomcat, ejb, cluster-computing, openejb, propagation

Is it possible to invoke a specific EJB in all servers if my application is in a clustered environment? For instance I want to notify all servers for a specific update. Currently I am using a JMS topic to send the notification. The EJBs are deployed in Tomcat with OpenEJB

Thanks!

Comment: Sending a JMS message to a Topic where several MDBs are listening is a great approach.  It's unclear what the actual question is.  Sounds like all is well.

Comment: Hi David, I agree on the JMS Topic, I was just wondering if it was possible to achieve this with a single EJB Call

Comment: MessageDriven Beans are EJBs, so technically you can :)  But for SessionBeans there's no broadcast support of any kind.  You could get clever though.  Say maybe an interceptor that broadcasts invocations to a JMS topic, then an MDB that pulls the message and invokes an EJB via reflection using the data from the JMS message.